# NoReverseMatch at /property/city/city/

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am developing a web commerce Django app and keep running into this bug.
[image]
Below are some screenshots. Any help is appreciated.

***Models.py***
[image]

***Urls.py***
[image]

***Views.py***[image]

***Template***[image]

Comment: Instead of images post code, look into https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Pass `city.slug`, not the whole `City` object in `get_neighborhood_url`  and use iklinac's advice.

Comment: ...and correct the path to path('city/..../<neighborhood_slug>/

Comment: Thanks, it worked, @iklinac I will follow your advice next time.